# there is no response when I install mongo

Tags: mongodb

mongo version: mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.6-signed

It succeeded in another computer.

I do as README but nothing happend..
What should I do ?

```
 PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> mongod --config D:\mongodb\Server\3.2\mongo.config
 PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>



PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> mongod  --dbpath D:\mongodb\Server\3.2\data\db
PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mongod -vvvv ...` for verbose output during sturtup.

Comment: `PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> mongod -vvvv  --dbpath D:\mongodb\Server\3.2\data\db`
`PS D:\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>`                                                        nothing happend